# Alternate Between Relative and Absolute Path in Same Loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, directory, relative-path

I am trying to:

1. Loop through a directory of CSV files
2. Append the file name as a new column to each file
3. Concatenate every file into single master file

But I get stuck at step #3, when converting the absolute path back into a relative path because my output looks like `../../../../Desktop/2018.12.31.csv` when I just want it to be `2018.12.31`.

For example, say the directory contains two files: `2018.12.31.csv` and `2018.11.30.csv`.

**2018.12.31.csv**

```
A B
1 2
```

**2018.11.30.csv**

```
A B
3 4
```

After running my program:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = ('/Users/user/Desktop/copy')
files = os.listdir(folder)
file_list = list()

for file in files:

    file = os.path.join(folder, file)
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")
        df['filename'] = os.path.relpath(file)
        file_list.append(df)

all_days = pd.concat(file_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
all_days.to_csv("/Users/user/Desktop/copy/all.csv")
```

I want the output to be:

```
A B filename
1 2 2018.12.31
3 4 2018.11.30
```

But instead it's:

```
A B filename
1 2 ../../../../Desktop/copy/2018.12.31.csv
3 4 ../../../../Desktop/copy/2018.11.30.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.relpath` returns the file location relative to your current directory. You can get the original filename using `os.path.basename(path)`, or just keep the filename as a separate variable and set `df['filename'] = file_orig`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the full filepath to the `.csv` files, you can use the `os.path` module to get just the filename:

```
df['filename'] = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file)[1])[0]
```

`os.path.splitext()` splits the path string in to a tuple with the extension as the second element.
`os.path.split()` splits the path string into a tuple with the filename (including extension) as the second element.

If you are only ever using `.csv` files you could simplify to:

```
df['filename'] = os.path.split(file)[1][:-4]
```